# Control LIVOLO switch with raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, home-automation, radio-transmission

I am using 433mhz module to control light switches with my raspberry pi by using 433utils library.
I was trying to control **livolo** brand light switches but it wont work with that library.
in this github there is a source code that should do the work but i can't make the transmitter part to work:
https://github.com/rafflesgun/smarthome
does any one ever did this kind of project?

Answer (score 2):

Ironically I emailed you earlier for help :). But I have actually figured out how to quickly pair livolo switches using python and only a raspberry pi. Check it out if you like.

​I solved livolo light switch using this technique and it can be applied to many livolo switches and you DON'T need a remote!

You simply put your light switch into discovery mode (hold down switch for 5 seconds).
After the switch beeps, run

`python livolo.py on`

You should hear your switch beep again, and that will mean it is paired!

'OFF' is actually ALL OFF, so that should work out of box!
`python livolo.py off`

https://github.com/midorineko/rpi_automation/blob/master/livolo.py

Answer (score 0):

I used the library in LamPI-3.x and it's working fine for me
https://github.com/platenspeler/LamPI-3.x/tree/master/transmitters/livolo

It's the same transmitter code but more updated. I also used the flag -r 200 to add more repeats as the livolo didn't catch the signal with the default 100 repeats.